# Ask password in LAContext Swift

Tags: ios

i am trying to implement the TouchID validation in my app. I have found many examples explaining how to do it (and i did it) but the thing is i don't know how to give the user the posibility of enter his/her password if he/she want to.
And also i want to know the best way of closing my app if for example the user decided to press "Cancel" button in the TouchID's alertview. Thanks!!

Here is my code:

```
    func validaIdentidad(){
    var touchIDContext = LAContext()
    var msgError : NSError?
    var alerta = UIAlertController(title:"", message:"", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alerta.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Understand", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {alertAction in
        alerta.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)}))

    if touchIDContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &msgError) {
        touchIDContext.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
            localizedReason: "Please authenticate using your fingerprint",
            reply: {(success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if success {
                    //si valida, dejo abrir la app
                    self.transicion()
                } else {
                    alerta.title = "Error"
                    switch error!.code {
                    case LAError.UserCancel.toRaw():
                        alerta.message = "Accion cancelada"
                        self.presentViewController(alerta, animated:true, completion:nil)
                        exit(0)
                    case LAError.AuthenticationFailed.toRaw():
                        alerta.message = "Error verificando tu identidad"
                    case LAError.UserFallback.toRaw():
                        alerta.message = "Usuario quiero ingresar passcode"
                    default:
                        alerta.message = "Error genérico"
                    }
                    //exit(0)
                    //self.presentViewController(alerta, animated:true, completion:nil)
                }
        })
    }
    else {
        alerta.title = "Nope!"
        switch msgError!.code {
        case LAError.TouchIDNotAvailable.toRaw():
            alerta.message = "Este dispositivo no tiene Touch ID"
        case LAError.TouchIDNotEnrolled.toRaw():
            alerta.message = "No se ha configurado el Touch ID"
        case LAError.PasscodeNotSet.toRaw():
            alerta.message = "No se ha configurado un PassCode"
        default:
            alerta.message = "Error Genérico"
        }
        self.presentViewController(alerta, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }//cierre else
}//cierre func ValidaIdentidad
```